# How to connect Mailchimp subscribers with Firebase using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, database, firebase, mailchimp

I have my database with Firebase and now I'm trying to do a newsletter subscription, but I want to save the subscribers in Mailchimp and Firebase.

Mailchimp connection works perfectly, but I don't know how to integrate the Firebase connection in the same js.

This is what I have in the `<head>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  angular.module("productLaunch", ["mailchimp"])
</script>
```

This in the `<body>` tag

```
<body ng-app="productLaunch"><section class="container-fluid subscribe" ng-controller="MailchimpSubscriptionCtrl">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <!-- Let us your email -->
      <div class="">
        <h2 class="text-center">Subscribe to our news</h2>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 mt centered">
          <h4 ng-hide="mailchimp.result ==='success'">LET ME KNOW WHEN YOU LAUNCH</h4>
          <h4 ng-show="mailchimp.result ==='success'">THANKS FOR SIGNING UP!</h4>
        </div>
        <form class="form-inline" role="form" ng-hide="mailchimp.result === 'success'">
          <input class="hidden" type="hidden" ng-model="mailchimp.username" ng-init="mailchimp.username='stopappweb'">
          <input class="hidden" type="hidden" ng-model="mailchimp.dc" ng-init="mailchimp.dc='us12'">
          <input class="hidden" type="hidden" ng-model="mailchimp.u" ng-init="mailchimp.u='3eb39be3ad857e60b357fdb5e'">
          <input class="hidden" type="hidden" ng-model="mailchimp.id" ng-init="mailchimp.id='520ddfd981'">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="mailchimp.email">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="mailchimp.email" placeholder="Enter email" ng-model="mailchimp.email">
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" ng-disabled="MailchimpSubscriptionForm.$invalid" ng-click="addSubscription(mailchimp)" type="submit" value="SIGN UP" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>

          <div ng-show="mailchimp.result === 'error'">
            <p ng-bind-html="mailchimp.errorMessage" class="error"></p>
          </div>
        </form> 
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
```

And this is my JS:

```
    'use strict';

angular.module('mailchimp', ['ng', 'ngResource', 'ngSanitize'])


  .controller('MailchimpSubscriptionCtrl', ['$log', '$resource', '$scope',
              function ($log, $resource, $scope) {


    $scope.myData = new Firebase("https://stopappwebpre.firebaseio.com/subscriptors");

    // Handle clicks on the form submission.
    $scope.addSubscription = function (mailchimp) {
      var actions,
          MailChimpSubscription,
          params,
          url;


      $scope.myData.push({mailchimp.email:$scope.mailchimp.email});

      // Create a resource for interacting with the MailChimp API
      url = 'http://' + mailchimp.username + '.' + mailchimp.dc + '.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json';
      params = {
        'EMAIL': mailchimp.email,
        'FNAME': mailchimp.fname,
        'LNAME': mailchimp.lname,
        'c': 'JSON_CALLBACK',
        'u': mailchimp.u,
        'id': mailchimp.id
      };
      actions = {
        'save': {
          method: 'jsonp'
        }
      };
      MailChimpSubscription = $resource(url, params, actions);

      // Send subscriber data to MailChimp
      MailChimpSubscription.save(
        // Successfully sent data to MailChimp.
        function (response) {
          // Define message containers.
          mailchimp.errorMessage = '';
          mailchimp.successMessage = '';

          // Store the result from MailChimp
          mailchimp.result = response.result;

          // Mailchimp returned an error.
          if (response.result === 'error') {
            if (response.msg) {
              // Remove error numbers, if any.
              var errorMessageParts = response.msg.split(' - ');
              if (errorMessageParts.length > 1)
                errorMessageParts.shift(); // Remove the error number
              mailchimp.errorMessage = errorMessageParts.join(' ');
            } else {
              mailchimp.errorMessage = 'Sorry! An unknown error occured.';
            }
          }
          // MailChimp returns a success.
          else if (response.result === 'success') {
            mailchimp.successMessage = response.msg;
          }
        },

        // Error sending data to MailChimp
        function (error) {
          $log.error('MailChimp Error: %o', error);
        }
      );


    }; }]);
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: There's nothing related to Firebase in your code right now. Adding that for you is a bit beyond the scope of what we do here on StackOverflow. The Firebase web site has great documentation to get you started, for example its [web quickstart](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/quickstart.html) or [AngularFire quickstart](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html). If you get stuck, post a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the question you have.

Comment: If you see the JS code, you can see the Firebase connection, and it works, bus I'm not sure if tis works for save the subscriber into Firebase: $scope.myData.push({mailchimp.email:$scope.mailchimp.email});